# Функции в Python, для чего использовано [0] в конце строки?

Tags: python

Для чего используется [0] в конце кода?

```
  bestmukey = min([(i[0], np.linalg.norm(x-mu[i[0]])) \
                for i in enumerate(mu)], key=lambda t:t[1])[0]
```

Полная версия:

```
clusters  = {}
for x in X:
    bestmukey = min([(i[0], np.linalg.norm(x-mu[i[0]])) \
                for i in enumerate(mu)], key=lambda t:t[1])[0]
    try:
        clusters[bestmukey].append(x)
    except KeyError:
        clusters[bestmukey] = [x]
```

Answer (score 7):

Давайте разберём это выражение по частям:

```
bestmukey = min([(i[0], np.linalg.norm(x-mu[i[0]])) for i in enumerate(mu)], key=lambda t:t[1])[0]
```

Заменим выражение-генератор на какую-нибудь переменную:

```
bestmukey = min(some_iterable, key=lambda t:t[1])[0]
```

Мы ищем минимальный элемент в каком-то множестве. Судя по наличию у функции `min` аргумента `key`, сравнивать непосредственно элементы множества мы не можем (или не хотим). Зато можем сравнивать результат вычисления `key` над элементами. Следовательно, в множестве содержатся сложные объекты. Какие? Смотрим на генератор, создающий это множество:

```
[(i[0], np.linalg.norm(x-mu[i[0]])) for i in enumerate(mu)]
```

Множество - массив, состоящий из кортежей. Примерно, такой:

```
[(a, b), (c, d), (e, f), ...]
```

Значит, `min(some_iterable, key=lambda t:t[1])` ищет минимальный из этих кортежей, причём для сравнения использует второй элемент каждого кортежа. Это можно понять, присмотревшись к функции, передаваемой в качестве аргумента `key` в `min`:

```
lambda t:t[1]
```

Не забываем, что нумерация начинается с нуля, поэтому `t[1]` - второй элемент.

Итак, `min` возвращает кортеж, чей второй элемент минимален. Теперь мы получаем выражение вроде этого:

```
bestmukey = (a, b)[0]
```

Теперь совершенно очевидно, что `[0]` в конце должен вернуть первый элемент полученного кортежа. Собирая всё воедино: в этой строке мы получаем первый элемент кортежа, имеющего минимальный второй элемент, из множества, созданного при помощи генератора `[(i[0], np.linalg.norm(x-mu[i[0]])) for i in enumerate(mu)]`.

Comment: Спасибо!!! Очень подробно и понятно)